# Difference between multiple proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, proportion

There are 5 companies and I need to compare proportion of experienced over inexperienced employees and conclude if there is a statistical difference in those proportions between the 5 companies.

The data look like this:

[image]

Could you tell me which test I should use to test the hypothesis?
Thanks

Comment: We do have a tag proportion. Perhaps one of the 700+ questions there might help you as it is not quite clear to me what hypothesis you have about the differences.

Comment: @mdewey Thank you for the suggestion. I added proportion tag.

I would say that the null hypothesis is that all five proportions are equal and alternative hypothesis is that there is at least one proportion different than others.